# Python - I'm trying to get the output of pwd and instead i get the exit status

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the output of `pwd`:

```
#!python
import os
pwd = os.system("pwd")
print (pwd)
```

it prints 0 which is the successful exit status instead the path.
How can i get the path instead?

Comment: With `subprocess.Popen` you can store stdout/stderr in variables.

Comment: I hope you understand that for that particular purpose you should use os.getcwd() .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Running system commands is better done with [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), but if you are using `os` already, why not just do

```
pwd = os.getcwd()
```

[`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) is available on Windows and Unix.

Comment: Also on MAC! (also Unix like - but just in case...) I've just used it :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the current working directory, use [os.getcwd()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd). But in general, if you want both the output and the return code:

```
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
errcode = proc.returncode
print(out)
print(errcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `os.system`, although `os.popen` does return that value for you:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.popen('pwd').read()
'/c/Python27\n'
```

However the `subprocess` module is much more powerful and should be used instead:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('pwd', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()[0]
'/c/Python27\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Current directory full path:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```